# Search List and update at that particular index

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to do a simple modification of items in a list by index.

Lets say in my foreach loop:

```
    foreach (User usr in userList)
    {
        if (uname.Text == usr.uname)
```

If it matches what i've typed in, how can i update the entire item in that particular index? Thanks!

Comment: your question isn't very clear. Are u trying to update the item in userlist??

Comment: Yes im trying to update items in a particular index, every index contains (uname, password, Address, Phone, Email). How can i just update only uname, address, phone and email and dont update the password?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a new instance to the item at particular index use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<userList.Count; i++)
{
      if (uname.Text == userList[i].uname)
      {
           userList[i] = /* new instance */
      }
}
```

Comment: Im not very good in c#, if at every index contains (uname, password, Address, Phone, Email). How can i just update only uname, address, phone and email and let password remains the same?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every object in userList contains  (uname, password, Address, Phone, Email) code should look something like this:

```
foreach (User usr in userList)
{
    if (uname.Text == usr.uname)
    {
        uname.Email= newEmail; // where newEmail is local variable with new value for password
        uname.Phone = newPhone;
        // ... changing other properties, just don't change Password property
    }
 }
```

Basically when you find object that you want to change, you can directly access its public properties and methods.